# 6 дивов в два ряда

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Как мне сделать 6 дивов в два ряда, чтобы они ровно шли друг за другом?

Comment: Очень странный вопрос :)

Comment: Согласен с тобой )))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Надо 3 дива в первом ряду и 3 дива во втором? Если да, то [вот](http://jsfiddle.net/Pq2Vr/)

```css
div {
  padding: 30px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>123</div>
<div>123</div>
<div>123</div>
<br/>
<div>123</div>
<div>123</div>
<div>123</div>
```

Comment: Да, то что надо, пасибо

Comment: Да, всегда пожалуйста.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему такое решение не работает http://jsfiddle.net/QCvUZ/ ? У каждого дива display:inline, у ряда дивов display:block, вроде бы второй ряд должен оказаться в новой строке, но оно все в одну склеивается.

Comment: @beardog
вместо `float:none;` напишите `clear:both;`

Answer (score 3):

если отступ в 1% не мешает можно сделать просто

```
.left-div, .center-div, .right-div {
    float:left;
    width:33%;
}
```

иначе так

```
.left-div {
    float:left;
    width:33%;
}
.center-div {
    float:left;
    width:34%;
}
.right-div {
    float:left;
    width:33%;

}
```

Comment: Ну это получается фиксированная ширина... Немного не то.

Comment: А ведь можно было упомянуть об этом в своем вопросе.

Comment: > А ведь можно было упомянуть об этом в своем вопросе.

а еще в вопросе можно было учесть миллион других тонкостей и ньюансов

Answer (score 0):

**одинаковая ширина ячеек:**

```css
.row {
  width: 300px;
}

.row > div {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

**по содержимому:**

```css
.row {
  width: 300px;
  display: table;
}

.row > div {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div>11111111111111</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>55555555555555</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Обёртке написать display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;
А колонкам max-width: 33.333%; или max-width: 25%;